# How Do I Authenticate a User via OAuth 2.0 when I'm the "Third Man Out"?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, cloud

I have a bit of a puzzle that I cannot figure out.  For me, it's so convoluted that I've produced a "request for help" video because I believe that in this case a picture really does "say a thousand words".

I've done my homework and haven't found anyone describing this situation anywhere.  I may very well be the first person to coin the phrase "Third Man Out" in this context.

If anyone has any recommendations on how to deal with this conundrum, I'd be happy to hear from you.

The video is 4 minutes long and I've done my best to keep things succinct.  The link to my request for help is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnepSmH_Qcg

Keywords:  Google App Engine, Google Cloud SQL, OAuth 2.0 Google Developers

Comment: can you provide what you've tried ?

Comment: Hi Philippe.  There's nothing to provide yet.  I'm at the very beginning of the design stage.  This is a decision that has to be made from the outset, before the very first line of code is minted.

Comment: I've been thinking about this all day and I _believe_ that, in Google OAuth's case, it returns a unique and unchanging "id" field along with the user's "e-mail".  I think that if the third-party app  that is both using my API and an OAuth API to authenticate the user is able to provide me with those two pieces of information (id + e-mail) that it should be enough to reasonably authenticate the user.  Any thoughts?  Is this poor reasoning?

Comment: I'm now researching something called the _Google Identity Toolkit_ (GIT).  If this service provides a couple of pieces of unique and unchanging data, that would be great.  I'd have a "user ID" on my end for my service and request that the third-parties send along the unique ID provided by GIT.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following provides the necessary design flow for an OAuth situation when you're the "third man out":   http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/4256785/